# Variables in POM dependencies. How maven knows artifact id of SWT?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The dependencies of `piccolo2d-swt` are described [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.piccolo2d/piccolo2d-swt/1.3.1) as

```
Group: ${swt.groupId}
Artifact: ${swt.artifactId}
Version: [3.3.0-v3346,)
```

How can this be resolved? Where does it take the values of variables?

If I run empty project with this dependency, it displays some error message, where it mentions `org.eclipse.swt.win32`.

Where did it took this value?

If I printout the value of these variables, I get nothing.

The POM is here

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Test_DisplayMavenVariables</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_DisplayMavenVariables</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <properties>
        <testproperty>This is a test property</testproperty>
    </properties>


    <!--    
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.piccolo2d</groupId>
            <artifactId>piccolo2d-swt</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
     -->

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>Displaying value of some properties</echo>
                                <echo>[testproperty] ${testproperty}</echo>
                                <echo>[swt.artifactId] ${swt.artifactId}</echo>
                                <echo>[swt.groupId] ${swt.groupId}</echo>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>


        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.1,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: can you please share you log file here ..

Answer (score 2):

The `swt.groupId` and `swt.artifactId` variables are being defined via maven profiles in the [piccolo2d-swt pom file](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/piccolo2d/piccolo2d-swt/1.3.1/piccolo2d-swt-1.3.1.pom), for example:

```
<profile>
  <id>windows_x86</id>
  <activation>
    <os>
      <family>windows</family>
      <arch>x86</arch>
    </os>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <swt.groupId>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32</swt.groupId>
    <swt.artifactId>x86</swt.artifactId>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

A profile is being defined for each platform and the profile is activated based on the `os.family` and `os.arch` detected when you run maven.

Comment: And why don't these variables visible for antrun?

Comment: Those properties (variables) are defined in the pom of the piccolo2d-swt dependency, and are not defined in  your pom. If you defined those properties somewhere in your pom (or parent pom) then antrun would have values to display.